# Retrieving all the pairs of numbers that sum to a target in a list

Tags: java, python, algorithm, list

Suppose I have a list `[1,2,3,4,4]` and a target `5`. I need to find all the pairs from the list which sum to 5, i.e., `(1,4),(1,4),(2,3)`. Can someone suggest me an algorithm how to solve it in less than `O(n^2)`.
I cam across this question while preparing for interview but I am not able to solve it in less than `O(n^2)`.
   Any Help is appreciated

Comment: You need to show _your_ attempt at solving this first.

Comment: Learn more about Hash Map and then try it.

Comment: I tried comparing one element with all elements

Comment: Rather than a terse and vague description of your code please just show it instead.

Comment: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2973/generalised-3sum-k-sum-problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, let me *show the idea*, and you'll *implement* it, OK?

**First stage**. Create a dictionary (Map) where `key = number`, `value = number's occurrencies`. E.g. for `[1, 2, 3, 4, 4]` we should have

```
 {1, 1}, // we have exactly one 1
 {2, 1}, //               - / - 2
 {3, 1}, //               - / - 3
 {4, 2}  //         we have two 4's
```

you can create such a dictionary in *linear time* `O(N)`.

**Second stage**. Scan the array, for each `item` look at the dictionary for the `key = 5 - item` and repeat
`(item, 5 - item)` pair `value` times. E.g. for `[1,2,3,4,4]` we'll have

```
 item | key | value | output
 -----------------------------------
    1 |   4 |     2 | (1, 4), (1, 4)
    2 |   3 |     1 | (2, 3)
    3 |   2 |     1 | (3, 2)
    4 |   1 |     1 | (4, 1)
    4 |   1 |     1 | (4, 1)
```

As you can see the second stage is also `O(N)`